# Luggage rack attachments for laptops?

Tags: product-rec, rack, luggage, diy

So, while out riding my bike, I *really* dislike having a backpack on.  I have a [trek luggage rack](http://store.trekbikes.com/jump.jsp?sort=2&bShopOnline=0&itemID=978&itemType=PRODUCT&RS=1&keyword=racks&CatID=186) on my bicycle and would love to find something that could attach to it, capable of holding a 17" laptop, preferably in a hard case, with padding.  I would really hate to lose the laptop (or its drive stability) to a fall/crash or even just the basic road vibrations and bumps...

Has anyone seen a product like this, or potentially know a good way to build something like this? :)

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet for weatherproof and crash worthiness is going to be a pelican case. They have a whole series of cases for laptops.
http://www.pelican.ca/case_group_search.php?CaseGroup=Laptop

I've personally taken a 'hardback' case on a paddling trip and it held up great. Many pelican products also have a warranty against failure as well so if the product does leak you've at least got a new case and a replacement laptop.

If you get one of their other cases you can also lock the case which will assist in keeping it secure from a thief. Yeah it's not going to stop a determined person but at the least it will give you time to realize and change any vital personal information.

Past that make sure you backup your data with something like Mozy.com. At some point you'll have a drive failure no matter what.

Comment: If I'm seeing this correctly, you'd need to put one of these into a pannier or strap it to the top of a rack, correct? These look like they'd stand up to biking quite well, nice find!

Comment: Yeah they'd hold up to crashes even. I've dropped my SLR down a 40foot tumble off a short cliff into a river. We chased it down and though the box was banged up I still use it and my camera was safe.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is Ortlieb l bought Office pannier which l can recommend give it is waterproof, robust and the way it attaches to the rack works. This is what l use for my company laptop in a padded bag.  If you are looking for something tougher try [Office 2 bag](http://www.ortlieb.co.uk/black-21l-officebag-classic.html)  I did not go for this one based on price and weight, that said it looks like it would offer more protection, and would be waterproof.  Vital in Sunny Scotland :-)

Comment: Dead Link here...

Answer (score 3):

The case below is not a hard case but it is well padded, and attaches securely with very little sway. It also includes a rain cover. It's my favorite.

[Jandd 19 inch laptop case](http://www.bikewagon.com/Jandd-19-inch-Laptop/Bike-Accessories/Bags/Panniers-Rack-Bags-p8557116.html)

I've also used padded sleeves and just slipped them in either my messenger bag or one of my panniers.

I haven't seen a hard case that attaches to bike rack but there certainly may be one out there.

Answer (score 1):

The [Topeak MTX Office Bag](http://topeak.com/products/Bags/MTXOfficeBag) claims to fit a 17" laptop in a "padded laptop compartment". The bag will only work (well) with a Topeak MTX rack, but with the right rack the bag will slide and snap securely to the rack.

It doesn't look like it'd survive a direct collision, but in that case the laptop would probably be the least of your worries.

Answer (score 1):

I use an [Arkel bug](http://www.arkel-od.com/us/bug-cummuting-bag-1.html) with the laptop compartment which fits my Mac (36.5 x 25 cm rectangular which is a 17.4" diagonal) and it works like a charm.  It converts to a backpack which helps since I bike to and from the train.

[image]

I wouldn't go with that color.  They have others which are more reflective to headlights, and sell a bright yellow raincover.

Comment: A separate raincover is a good idea - its a separate layer of protection, which you can remove to dry, rather than carting a wet bag about.