# Best cargo storage on a commuter bike

Tags: commuter, product-rec, cargo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pros and cons panniers and messenger bags](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/820/pros-and-cons-panniers-and-messenger-bags)

I commute about 5 miles each way to work. I usually travel light; I don't carry much with me other than the contents of my pockets. Sometimes I need to take my laptop home for a night or a weekend, to be able to get some work done or be on call. And sometimes on weekends I run errands on my bike, and need to pick something up at the store.

There are several options for carrying things on my bike. I've tried my backpack, but that usually leaves my back covered in sweat when I get to work or get home. I've tried my laptop case, which has a shoulder strap, but that hangs down a little too low so it sometimes interferes with me getting back up in my saddle, and it sometimes slides around to my side so I need to adjust it while riding. Some other options would be a rack and panniers, a front basket, or a messenger bag.

Which will work best for somewhat flexible storage needs, be able to carry a laptop safely, and not add too much weight when I want to ride light and not carry anything with me?

Comment: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/820/pros-and-cons-panniers-and-messenger-bags/822#822

Comment: @wdypdx22 Ah, yep. This pretty much duplicates that question; I didn't find that one when searching. I'll vote to close as a dupe.

Comment: Added my vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: added vote to close

Comment: To answer your question though - you want a rack (-:

Comment: I don't think the title on the other question is as good as the title for this question. I agree that it covers similar grounds, but this question would be easier to find.

Comment: @deemar Yes, that's probably why I could find it when I searched. We could try editing the title on the other question, but I don't have enough rep to do that yet.

Comment: I added the "cargo" tag on the other question; that should help.