# Medium Budget Road Bikes for India

Tags: product-rec, bike-selection

Bikers of Indian subcontinent, can you enumerate few medium budget road bikes for beginners with its pros/cons.

Comment: SE really isn't a good place for this. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for details.

Comment: Depends what your roads are like - you're best served by looking at what other riders are on, and get something similar.   Mudguards/fenders will be a good idea.

Comment: @Batman - I am new here and would like to not step on toes but learn from you all. I went through help center and understand that this might seem like product-rec. But there are questions about product rec present in the forum which are not closed/on-hold. Example > http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4046/recommendation-for-panniers-to-carry-a-laptop-for-daily-commute-thats-available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the intended use of the bicycle ? Commuting? Racing?

As far as I know, Indian weather can be very diverse from near desert areas to jungle and seasonal monsoons... with and without mountains.

If it is mostly commuting, I'd get a "good" hybrid bicycle if you can store it safely, or a simple old road bike (well maintained) that you don't care that much if it gets stolen or damaged.

If it is for racing or training, I'd get one of those new "gravel" bikes with the best tires you can get to limit the risk of punctures.

As for which bike to get, it depends on your budget and availability near where you live.

Comment: Use - Basic fitness, occasional competitive events, regular commuting within city for short distances to avoid traffic hassles and reduce carbon footprint.

Comment: You might benefit from a cyclocross bike, best of both worlds, could easily switch tires from knobbies to slicks for different uses. The 700c wheels would make for a good commuter and the ruggedness of a cyclocross frame will put up with any abuse you can provide.